# Subtracting an int column from a date column with date_add in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe `df`

```
+------------+------+
|  timestamp | days |
+------------+------+
| 2019-11-21 |    5 |
| 2019-10-22 |   21 |
|        ... |  ... |
+------------+------+
```

I want to subtract the days from the timestamp with

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.withColumn("timestamp", F.date_add(F.col("timestamp"), -F.col("days")))
```

Expected result would be

```
+------------+------+
|  timestamp | days |
+------------+------+
| 2019-11-16 |    5 |
| 2019-10-01 |   21 |
|        ... |  ... |
+------------+------+
```

But I only get an error `TypeError: Column is not iterable`

Is there a way to get this to work?

Comment: Specifically: `df.withColumn("timestamp", F.expr("date_add(timestamp, -days)")`

Comment: This works even better! Please add your answer.

Comment: it's the same as the duplicate I linked. You can accept the duplicate and close it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Using a udf was the solution.

```
date_add_udf = F.udf(lambda date, days: F.date_add(date, days), pyspark.sql.types.TimestampType())
```

And then calling the it

```
df.withColumn("timestamp", date_add_udf(F.col("timestamp"), -F.col("days")))
```

Comment: When I try this method, I get an error like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53751266/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-jvm-pyspark-udf). It looks like pyspark.sql.functions are not allowed inside of UDFs. Is this particular to Databricks?

Comment: Just found [an alternate answer](https://newbedev.com/how-to-subtract-a-column-of-days-from-a-column-of-dates-in-pyspark). You use expr() instead of a UDF.